# select option jquery hide() is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show/hide select option based on some conditions. Its working fine in Firefox but not working in IE. I don't want to use remove() because I want to retain the data to show again on different conditions.

IE Version 10, jQuery v1.11.3

```
$('#ddl').children('option').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('e-id') != 4) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Create a fiddle and give your code snippet here. Hiding options is not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Provide: the problematic code, the version of jQuery your using, and the version of IE you are using.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, like html

Comment: hide() and show()  function works over the browsers, but with looking at the html code , its very hard to say where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support some css properties on option tag. Ones that I know are

**display, height, visibility, pointer-events**

```css
option:first-child, &:nth-child(3){
  color: red;
}

option:nth-child(2){
  font-weight: bold;
}

option:nth-child(4){
  font-size: 30px;
}

option:nth-child(5){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
  <option disabled>F</option>
  <option>G</option>
  <option>H</option>
  <option>I</option>
</select>
```

But you can make the option disabled if you don't want user to select it.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `prop` to replace `attr`

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.